# Cannot mount a folder with Docker

Tags: docker

I can't get the -v option to work with Docker. My host is Linux Mint and my image is using Ubuntu:latest.

```
sudo docker run -it opencv:latest -v /home/rr/Desktop/mytest:/src
```

It gives the error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
container_linux.go.345: starting container process caused 
"exec: \"-v\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

I have tried different things. Both mounting to a folder in the image that exists and one that does not, but it is the same error either way.

Comment: the image needs to go last. everything after is just treated as command executed in the container. So `docker run -it  -v /home/rr/Desktop/mytest:/src opencv:latest` should work

Comment: `docker run` options like `-v` need to go _before_ the image name.  After the image name, it's interpreted as the command to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usage of `docker run` is:

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

So your options need to go before the image name, including the `-v` option. If you put it after the image name, it sees it as the command to run instead of an option. Try:

```
sudo docker run -it -v /home/rr/Desktop/mytest:/src opencv:latest
```

Comment: Thank you. Works without a problem now.